# Python Authlib : How To Resolve Auth Code Challenge And Verify Tokens Stored In HTTP Only Session Cookie Of Protected Endpoint?

Tags: python, openid-connect, authlib

After reading the documentation I am struggling to understand how to use [Authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/) to implement Authorize Code Flow for an OpenID Connect provider. After reading the documentation I have had a go at implementing the following code listed below.

The `/login` endpoint uses authlib to redirect to authorization of Identity Provider, in this case Cognito. This redirects to `/aws_cognito_redirect` which I have currently implemented myself to resolve the code challenge to retrieve tokens.

My questions are:

- How to use `authlib` to also resolve the code challenge instead of implementing this part myself?
- Does [Authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/) provide functionality to return token(s) in HTTP Only cookie and verify tokens in subsequent requests containing the cookie? For example, does [Authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/) allow an endpoint to be decorated/marked to as protected, in which case it will verify the tokens in HTTP Only cookie?

**Update**

After inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/169c7dcfc47478c8d55553cc95fb0f5578162b77/authlib/integrations/starlette_client/apps.py#L49) I eventually figured out how to resolve the code challenge using [Authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/) with FastAPI. The source code is included at the end of this question.

I am leaving the question open since the second part remains unanswered.
Currently, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831576/authlib-token-validator-using-remote-authentication-server) suggests that it is possible to use `ResourceProtector` class that would do what I need. However, that has a `parse_request_authorization` method that inspects the Authorisation header of a request for a bearer token. So...I am assuming the approach is to subclass `ResourceProtector` class and override this method to inspect request for HTTP only cookie and extract the JWT contained within for verification?? Is this feature implemented and provided by [Authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/)?

Alternatively, also investigating to see if I can integrate [fastapi-login](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-login/) to achieve this functionality.

**Appendix: Source Code**

**Initial Source Code With Custom Implementation For Resolving Code Challenge**

```py
import base64
from functools import lru_cache

import httpx
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware

from . import config


@lru_cache()
def get_settings() -> config.Settings:
    """Create config settings instance encapsulating app config."""

    return config.Settings()


def get_auth_base_url(region: str, userpool_id: str) -> str:
    # base_url = "https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_QqNgzdtT5"

    base_url = "https://cognito-idp." + region + ".amazonaws.com/" + userpool_id

    return base_url


app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="secretly")

oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
    "cognito",
    client_id=get_settings().client_id,
    client_secret=get_settings().client_secret,
    server_metadata_url=get_auth_base_url(
        get_settings().region, get_settings().userpool_id
    )
    + "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    client_kwargs={"scope": "openid email"},
)


def encode_auth_header(client_id: str, client_secret: str) -> str:
    """Encode client id and secret as base64 client_id:client_secret."""

    secret = base64.b64encode(
        bytes(client_id, "utf-8") + b":" + bytes(client_secret, "utf-8")
    )

    return "Basic " + secret.decode()


@app.get("/login")
async def login(request: Request):
    """Redirect to /aws_cognito_redirect endpoint."""

    cognito = oauth.create_client("cognito")
    redirect_uri = request.url_for("read_code_challenge")

    return await cognito.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)


@app.get("/aws_cognito_redirect")
async def read_code_challenge(
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    settings: config.Settings = Depends(get_settings),
):
    """Retrieve tokens from oauth2/token endpoint and return session cookie."""

    code = request.query_params["code"]
    print("/aws_cognito_redirect received code := ", code)

    auth_secret = encode_auth_header(settings.client_id, settings.client_secret)

    headers = {"Authorization": auth_secret}
    print("Authorization:" + str(headers["Authorization"]))

    payload = {
        "client_id": settings.client_id,
        "code": code,
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "redirect_uri": settings.redirect_uri,
    }

    token_url = (
        "https://"
        + settings.domain
        + ".auth."
        + settings.region
        + ".amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token"
    )

    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tokens = await client.post(
            token_url,
            data=payload,
            headers=headers,
        )
        tokens.raise_for_status()

        print("Tokens\n" + str(tokens.json()))
        response.set_cookie(key="jwt", value=tokens.content, httponly=True)
```

**Updated Source Code To Demonstrate How To Resolve Code Challenge Using Authlib**

```py
import base64
from functools import lru_cache

from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware

from . import config


@lru_cache()
def get_settings() -> config.Settings:
    """Create config settings instance encapsulating app config."""

    return config.Settings()


@lru_cache
def get_auth_base_url(region: str, userpool_id: str) -> str:
    """Return cognito discover points base url from region and userpool ID."""

    return ("https://cognito-idp." + region + ".amazonaws.com/" + userpool_id)


app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="some-random-string")

oauth = OAuth()
cognito = oauth.register(
    "cognito",
    client_id=get_settings().client_id,
    client_secret=get_settings().client_secret,
    server_metadata_url=get_auth_base_url(
        get_settings().region, get_settings().userpool_id
    )
    + "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    client_kwargs={"scope": "openid email"},
)


def encode_auth_header(client_id: str, client_secret: str) -> str:
    """Encode client id and secret as base64 client_id:client_secret."""

    secret = base64.b64encode(
        bytes(client_id, "utf-8") + b":" + bytes(client_secret, "utf-8")
    )

    return "Basic " + secret.decode()


@app.get("/")
async def login(request: Request):
    """Redirect to /aws_cognito_redirect endpoint after sign-in."""

    redirect_uri = request.url_for("read_code_challenge")

    return await cognito.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)


@app.get("/aws_cognito_redirect")
async def read_code_challenge(request: Request):
    """Request a token from cognito using code challenge response."""

    return await cognito.authorize_access_token(request)
```